# No buffer space available, maximum connection reached

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
package Simple;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.text.*;

public class CurrentProg {
    //connecting to the database

  private static final String DB_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  private static final String DB_CONNECTION ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?autoReconnect=true"; 
  private static final String DB_USER = "root";
  private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "root";
  static Connection dbConnection = null;
  static Statement statement = null;

  static int total=1;

  //Searching between startdate and enddate

  public static java.util.LinkedList searchBetweenDates(java.util.Date startDate, java.util.Date endDate) {

        java.util.Date begin = new Date(startDate.getTime());
        java.util.LinkedList list = new java.util.LinkedList();
        list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
        java.util.Date end = new Date(endDate.getTime());
        endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime() + 24*3600*1000);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(begin);
       dbConnection = getDBConnection();

        while(begin.compareTo(endDate)<0){
        begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000);
        list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));        
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

        //For a single day calculation: 24hours*60mins=1440 /2 (2 mins time difference as per the requirement) = 720 

                for (int j = 0; j < 720; j++) {
                cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);            
                timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
                String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(timestamp);               
                String[] parts = S.split(" ");
                String date=parts[0];
                String time=parts[1];
                cal.getTime().toString();

           // To create data loop into a List
            List<String> records = new ArrayList<String>();
            StringBuffer record = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
            records = new ArrayList<String>(total);         

            int a2 = 220 + j % 31; // 230 - 244 by 1
            String wString = Integer.toString(a2);
            String a = String.valueOf(a2);   
            double b2 = 0.00 + j % 3.7  ; // 1.3 - 3.9 by 0.1 
            String aString = Double.toString(b2);
            String b = String.valueOf(b2);
            b = b.substring(0, Math.min(b.length(), 5));


          record.delete(0, record.length());
          record.append(a + "," + b  +  ",'"+  date + "', '"+  time + "'");
          record.append("\t\t");      
          record.append("\n");
          records.add(record.toString()); 

          //Insert Query
          String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO cmd1"
                  + "(a, b, date, time) " + "VALUES"
                  + "("+record.toString()+")";
                  System.out.println("insertTableSQL - " + insertTableSQL);             //  Statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);

          try {

                  statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                  statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
                  System.out.println("Record is inserted into Db table!");
                  } catch (SQLException e) {
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                  } 
      try {

            //  dbConnection = getDBConnection();
              statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
              statement.executeUpdate(insertTableSQL);
              System.out.println("Record is inserted into Db table!");
              } catch (SQLException e) {
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
              } 
        finally {
        //  httpPost.releaseConnection()
            try{
                 if(statement!=null)
                    statement.close();
              }
             finally{
             }

              try{
                 if(dbConnection!=null)
                    dbConnection.close();
              }
              finally{

              }

              }                                            
         }
        }
        }
        return list;
        }

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

      //To enter startDate and enddate
    //  EntityManagerFactory.getCache().evictAll;


    SimpleDateFormat  startDate=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    SimpleDateFormat  endDate=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

                java.util.LinkedList hitList = searchBetweenDates(
                startDate.parse("2016-01-01"),
                endDate.parse("2016-03-01"));
                String[] combo = new String[hitList.size()];
                for(int i=0; i<hitList.size(); i++)
                combo[i] = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(((java.util.Date)hitList.get(i)));

  }

private static void insertRecordIntodb() {
    //
  }
  private static Connection getDBConnection() {
    Connection dbConnection = null;
    try {
      Class.forName(DB_DRIVER);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    try {
      dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_CONNECTION, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
      return dbConnection;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return dbConnection;
  }  
}
```

Server connection failure during transaction. Due to underlying exception: 'java.net.SocketException: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect'.

```
** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:276)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2717)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1509)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:266)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at Simple.CurrentProg.getDBConnection(CurrentProg.java:186)
    at Simple.CurrentProg.searchBetweenDates(CurrentProg.java:126)
    at Simple.CurrentProg.main(CurrentProg.java:164)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **


Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Simple.CurrentProg.searchBetweenDates(CurrentProg.java:137)
    at Simple.CurrentProg.main(CurrentProg.java:164)
```

Here I am trying to connect java program with database but when i am trying to insert large data say for 1 month so its only fetching 16000 records not more than that i want the data should be inserted as per the given date range what should i do to get that . In stacktrace its showing an exception as no buffer space available maximum connection reached. Thanks In advance

Comment: posting the stacktrace might help

Comment: Formatting the code with correct indentations so us mere mortals can read it too might also help.

Comment: Your code has `if (statement!=null) dbConnection.close();`. I think you meant `statement.close()`. Errors like that won't happen if you use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: @Andreas yes you are right can you explore more i am not getting exactly by that example

Comment: The first thing you should do, is remove all `catch(SQLException se)` clauses and simply add `throws SQLException` to `searchBetweenDates()`. You're current hiding error messages, and allowing code to continue running even after an error has occurred. **BAD MOJO!!!**

Comment: 1. Put `dbConnection = getDBConnection();` before the `while` loop.It seems that you are creating too many DB connections. (Haven't experimented myself). 2. Close `statement` as Andreas suggested.

Comment: As @ujulu suggested, you should keep connection alive for the entire run of the method. Connecting to a database is sssllllloooooooowwwwww....... Doing it 720 times for one search operation is a performance killer. Also, use a `PreparedStatement` and parameter markers (`?`) in the SQL.

Comment: @ Andreas i am unable to use try catch block after completing while loop what should i do please suggest @ujulu

Comment: You should move the `dbConnection.close();` out of the `while` loop too.

Comment: did still problem is there

Comment: in stacktrace : there is an exception No operations allowed after connection closed.
i have edited above program too as my eclipse

Comment: OK, I'll post you the code. It might take a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the modified code. I removed a lot of code which is not necessary:

```
public static LinkedList<Date> searchBetweenDates(Date startDate, Date endDate) throws SQLException {
    Date begin = new Date(startDate.getTime());
    LinkedList<Date> list = new LinkedList<Date>();

    list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));

    endDate.setTime(endDate.getTime() + 24 * 3600 * 1000);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(begin);

    dbConnection = getDBConnection();
    PreparedStatement ps = dbConnection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO cmd1(aaaa, bbbb, datee, timee) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    while (begin.compareTo(endDate) < 0) {
        begin = new Date(begin.getTime() + 86400000);
        list.add(new Date(begin.getTime()));
        Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());

        // For a single day calculation: 24hours*60mins=1440 /2 (2 mins time
        // difference as per the requirement) = 720

        for (int j = 0; j < 720; j++) {
            cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 2);
            timestamp = new Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
            String S = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(timestamp);
            String[] parts = S.split(" ");
            String date = parts[0];
            String time = parts[1];
            cal.getTime().toString();

            // To create data loop into a List
            for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {

                int a2 = 220 + j % 31; // 230 - 244 by 1
                String a = String.valueOf(a2);
                double b2 = 0.00 + j % 3.7; // 1.3 - 3.9 by 0.1
                String b = String.valueOf(b2);
                b = b.substring(0, Math.min(b.length(), 5));

                ps.setString(1, a);
                ps.setString(2, b);
                ps.setString(3, date);
                ps.setString(4, time);

                ps.execute();
            }
        }
    }
    if (ps != null)
        ps.close();
    if (dbConnection != null)
        dbConnection.close();

    return list;
}
```

What I changed:

- I removed your try/catch's because I wanted to make the code short so that I can edit it here easily. But you should handle exception correctly. **And don't swallow exceptions ever.** I mean the following is **no go**:

  ```
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
  ```

It is very bad Idea because you'll not see the real cause of the problem in this case; at least do `e.printStackTrace()` eventhough it is not recommended in a real project.

- I exchanged the `Statement` object for `PreparedStatement` because it is much more efficient.
- Removed package names and put `import` statements instead because it is not necessary to do so unless you have different classes from different packages with the same name.
- I changed column names because my DB does not want to accept them. Column names like `a` are very bad. Choose instead descriptive names so that you might understand what it is for a couple of months later. Don't use column names like `date` because they are reserved words for some databases systems I know.
- **Don't create database resources like Connection in a loop** unless it is absolutely needed! Otherwise, your program will go out of resources because these resources are very expensive! That is exactly what you are experiencing right now.

Hope it helps, otherwise, drop me a comment.

Comment: its creating problem in main now

Comment: Can you describe the problem? Everything is working for me.

Comment: if this has solved the original problem you should accept it and post a new question with the new problem

Comment: @Joe 'It is giving me error' is. Ito a problem description, and you've already been told that new problems require new questions.

Comment: thank you so much :) i am getting output now as i wanted

Comment: Glad it helped you!

Comment: @ujulu can we make searchbetweenates method to do search only i mean is it possible to reaarange this code into 2 parts in first it should only search and the data which we are generating it should be in another class with insert query

Comment: Now I am at work. Please specify what you mean by search and I will see it today in the evening.

Comment: actually i am generating data too in the method searchbetweendates. work should be for searchbetweendates only to search dates, i dont want jdbc connection and data generation under that method i have to use different class for that and then to create reference from another class .want to format the code in proper manner

Comment: Do you mean you want to separate data generation from persisting those data into DB?

Comment: @ujulu   yes exactly searchbetweendates shoul only contains dates not more than that